# Python Tkinter, tk.Frame container widget error in method

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a GUI code that opens frame using Tkinter. I referred various websites. Now while testing I am facing problem. For example:

- In 1st frame, I select `MainController` button.
- in 2nd frame press `MC_CONFIG` button.
- in 3rd frame I set `XML PATH` then clicked `MC SYSTEM.xml` button

If I go to `Back to Home` button and follow the same procedure, `MC_CONFIG` button gets disabled (i.e I cannot go further).

If I comment(delete) this line(126)

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self)
```

in method `def nacxml(self):` of class `MC_CONFIG`, it is working perfectly.

The below one is just part of my main code bu facing problem here.
Please guide me.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import xml.dom.minidom
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox 
from array import *
import tkFileDialog
import os
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Switch Installer window")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        #for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
        for F in (StartPage, MainController,xmlpath,MC_CONFIG):
            frame = F(container,self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.modules_label = ['MAINCONTROLLER']
        self.modules_function = [MainController]
        self.modules_label_index = len(self.modules_label)
        self.modules_function_index = len(self.modules_function)
        print("self.modules_label_index = %s" %self.modules_label_index)

        label = Label(self, text="SWITCH INSTALLER", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #button = Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",

        button3 = Button(self, text="SELECT",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainController))
        button3.pack()

        label3 = Label(self, text="MainController", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label3.place(x= 50, y=100+10)
        button8 = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        button8.pack() 

class xmlpath(tk.Frame):
#xfilename="+++"
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.xfilename="srinivasan"
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button1 = Button(self, text="XML PATH",
                            command=self.newxmlpath)
        button1.pack()

    def newxmlpath(self,*args):
        # ObjNAC= NacHandler()
        self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        print(self.filename)
        #ObjNAC.temp_method(self,self.filename)
        return self.filename

class MainController(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = Label(self, text="|--Frame1 MainController --|", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        mc_button1 = Button(self, text="MC_CONFIG", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(MC_CONFIG))
        mc_button1.pack()

        mc_button2 = Button(self, text="MENU HOME", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        mc_button2.pack()

        self.pack (fill = BOTH, expand = 1)     

class MC_CONFIG(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        print "Inside MC_CONFIG"

        self.database = []
        # set root as parent
        self.parent = parent

        label1 = Label(self, text="|------------Frame2--MainController---------------|", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack(pady = 10,padx = 10)

        label2 = Label(self, text="Edit SYSTEM.xml File", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.pack(pady = 10,padx = 10)

        button1 = Button(self, text="XML PATH",
                            command=self.newxmlpath)
        button1.pack(pady = 10,padx = 10)

        button2 = Button(self, text = "MC SYSTEM.xml", command = self.nacxml)
        button2.pack(pady = 10,padx = 10)

        button3 = Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.pack(pady = 10,padx = 10)

    def newxmlpath(self, *args):
        self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        print(self.filename)
        return self.filename

    def nacxml(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        print "===Inside Nacxml1==="

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.geometry ("640x480+300+300")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the `tk.Frame.__init__(self)` line supposed to do? Do you need it? If you remove it, does something else stop working?

Comment: I wrote only partial code above. In full code  I added one more pack frame i.e it read values from xml file and show it in front end for editing.    Full code Link is  http://www.hastebin.com/ozerilogad.py

Comment: You say that if you remove that line, your code runs perfectly. So, why don't you just remove that line?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
def nacxml(self):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
```

You should only ever call the superclass constructor from within the constructor of the subclass. Doing so anywhere else will certainly not do whatever you think it's doing.

Comment: I removed this line tk.Frame.__init__(self) and working. Now I want to use Geometry manager like pack frame to edit file whatever read from xml file and keeping two options like Ok and Cancel. While Cancel I am using self.pack_forget to hide the frame but not getting desired output.Basically I want separate window need to opened so that I can edit the parameters. How it can be done?

Comment: @user2357643: if you have another question to ask, first do some research, and then click the "Ask Question" button.  Comments are for getting clarification only, not for asking completely new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally code is working as intended
1.Deleted  **tk.Frame.__init__(self)** as indicated by Bryan Oakley

```
 def nacxml(self):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
```

2.Controller is not intialized in self.But it is present in  **def __init__(self, parent, controller):**.Hence added 
*self.controller = controller* in MC_CONFIG class

```
class MC_CONFIG(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    print "Inside MC_CONFIG"
```

So can be used in below  method as self.controller.show_frame(StartPage)

```
def nacxml(self):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self)
    print "===Inside Nacxml1==="
    # xml read,edit,widget code will be added here
    self.controller.show_frame(StartPage)
```